# C# Monogame & Farseer Physics: Collisions

Tags: c#, box2d, monogame, farseer

I am a begginer. I am using Monogame and Farseer Physics Library in C#. (latest versions)

In my game, whenever my `ball` (circle) hits the `corner of a rectangle`, (or even another circle), it is supposed to only change direction on the Y-Axis.

However, it does not only change direction on the Y-Axis, (as intended), but it also moves a small amount to the right as well (or the left accordingly), depending on how you hit the corner (or another circle). It is as if some force is being put on the ball, making it move on X-Axis as well.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/rEbNTua.png?1]

This movement is cool and all, and it makes a lot of sense, but in my game, it does not, therefore i want to get rid of it.

How is this possible ? I am guessing i have to change some default values.

This what my coding looks like:

```
BallBody.BodyType = BodyType.Dynamic;
BlockBody.BodyType = BodyType.Static;
Ball.LinearVelocity = new Vector(0,-1); // ball going up
BallBody.OnCollision += Ball_OnCollision;

public bool Ball_OnCollision(Fixture f1, Fixture f2, Contact contact)
{
    // if the Ball (f1), collides with the Block (f2)
    if (f2.Body == BlockBody)
    // change the direction of the Ball on Y-Axis
    Ball.LinearVelocity = new Vector(0,-1);
    return true;
}
```

Also with high speeds, this occurs:

[image]

Even though the ball is never able to pass through the Block (tunneling), I want to know how could i possible fix that so that the ball never enters the Block area ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is surprisingly difficult to do with Box2D. The best I could manage when I tried, was to record the velocity of the ball when the contact started, and then when the contact ends, manually set the velocity to what I wanted. That works fine when the ball only begins and end contact with one block at a time, but in some cases the ball can begin touching two blocks in the same time step. You would have to look at the arrangement of the blocks it touched, and calculate for yourself what angle you would expect it to bounce away at. Eventually I just gave up and did not bother to cover that case.

Comment: for the ball it should be impossible to touch two rectangles at the same time, because a circle touches the bottom side of a rectangle with exactly 1 pixel accuracy, and 2 rectangles are never in the same pixel at the same time, true ?

Comment: I want to know BEFOREHAND when the collision happens (1 frame before), so i need a `OneFrameBeforeCollision` function , not `OnCollision`, i guess ? how can i implement something like this ? There are some Body.CollisionCategories properties (Categorie.Cat1 , Categorie.Cat2, ..., Categorie.Cat31) do you know perhaps if some of those 31 does what i am looking for easier ? I cant find any documentation for these. I dont even know what they do or if they help my case in any way.

Comment: The ball can easily touch two blocks at the same time if it hits a place where two blocks are touching each other, and it overlaps both of them. Unfortunately there is no beforehand check possible with Box2D, as it would not make sense - how can the physics engine know if you will apply a force before the next time step and change the direction of something...

Comment: "two blocks are touching each other" my blocks are never touching each other though, are they ? each block starts at the end of the other i think

Comment: Well, even if there is a gap between them, you can still place a circle so that it overlaps two blocks at the same time right?

Comment: i guess you are right, i have to do it manually so that it hits only 1 block at a time, cause i dont want it to hit 2, ive made a huge progress so far though, thanks a lot